# Magneto 2 top menu is not displaying on homepage

Tags: magento, magento2

I have installed Magento 2 Ortho Theme, And The top menu is not displaying on homepage, It displayed on all other pages except homepage. This is the link where menu not showing http://m2.eeprocess.ca/ and its displayed fine on inner pages http://m2.eeprocess.ca/shop-all-products.html

I checked the header file the code for display menu is below.

getChildHtml("navigation.sections"); ?>

Comment: For me it does not show on both links. What cache do you use, full_page or varnish? When I started I had a similar problem (menu was not showing at all) because of varnish cache. Try to eliminate all cache (fpc and varnish) and set your M2 to developer mode to check if cache is an issue.

Comment: I am using Varnish cache, Sorry this is the page where menu showing fine. http://m2.eeprocess.ca/catalog/product/view/id/155/s/extech-br250-4-video-borescope-wireless-inspection-camera/, How to eliminate all cache? I am using this command php bin/magento cache:clean. Is it right?

Comment: What I was suggesting was to turn it off completely to check if varnish is responsible. Just switch to default cache in STORES > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > System > Full Page Cache and re-deploy static content afterwards (maybe you have to clear pub/static/* var/cache/* and var/page_cache/* manually). Alternatively you could check your purge config of varnish. Refer to official documentation to do that: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html